# JNI_CreateJavaVM with jre 64bits

Tags: macos, qt, java-native-interface, x86-64, i386

I'm developing a Qt project on OS X.
I'm using Jni and include the header jni.h present in the Java jdk.
I'm using the function JNI_CreateJavaVM to create the vm, whose symbols are in the libclient.dylib (libjvm.dylib is the symbol link).

The problem is my app is 64 bits, whereas this library is for i386 architecture, so I cannot link/load it.
How can I use this function in a 64 bits application ?

My only choice is to build Qt in 32 bits, but I don't really like this, cause I'll be stuck in 32 bits forever...(unless java provide this lib for 64bits)

Comment: Problem solved, linking with -framework javaVm and moving my java app into the correct place solved the pb...Sorry about that.

Comment: Create an answer yourself and put the text from your comment in it. Then accept that answer.